Large air bubble under wallpaper
I have large air bubbles under the wallpaper in a room I'm renovating. The bubbles were there before we started painting but got slightly bigger after painting the wallpaper
A friend recommended a wallpaper perforator. Is this enough to fix large bubbles as seen in the photos?
The apartment was built in 1970 and I think he wallpaper is from the same time.
We painted over the wallpaper, then using a syringe to inject paste but it didn't hold. My friend also mentioned that we should have first fixed the wallpaper before painting it.


I have limited wallpaper experience, but here are my guesses as to what's happening based on general knowledge:

The bubbles were from ancient adhesive degrading over half a century.

The wallpaper swelled when moistened, which exacerbated the bubbling.

The paste repair failed because you're essentially trying to glue to dust.

Further repair attempts will likely result in similar frustration.


I would be slicing the bubbles away (along with any other loose paper), then skimming with topping compound or plaster (as is appropriate for your region) to conceal the edges, then sanding very lightly, priming, and painting again.

Early in my home renovation career I had this happen. I slit the bubbles and patched over them.
Then others appeared over the course of the next few days.
I just had to remove all the wallpaper, sand and skim the walls to make them smooth. Then prime and paint.
I learned to never try to paint wallpaper.

I painted over wallpaper many times without major issues. Normally the paint seems to be enough so that the wallpaper is reattached to the wall, especially if you it is only on the sides. I have never had to handle bubbles this size though

It's the one time that burns your britches that makes you learn to not paint wallpaper.  Hey if others want to, go ahead.  If I'm asked to I politely decline.
